# visual studio code working directory for subfolders

Tags: visual-studio-code

I opened a project directory using ^K^O

inside the project directory is a subdirectory (named 'code') with my python source files.

When I run the files using VS Code's debug session or Code-Runner the current working returned by python's os.getcwd() directory is the top-level project directory and not the actual directory of the code file.

Naturally, when running the code from the command line I get a different behavior.

How can I change the working directory of all the files in this project?

Can this be changed globally, so that the default behavior is that files are debugged from their actual directory?